# Possible changes and effects of law

Tags: discussion, scope

Do questions based on the effects of new laws fit in to this stack?

For example would I be ok to ask about possible effects of changing the stop and search powers of police?

Comment: I'm not sure about this - how would you judge whether an answer is correct or not? I think the closest would be asking whether similar examples of changing stop and search powers of police have existed, and what effects occurred. Also, [worldbuilding.se] might be useful.

Comment: My thinking was that a lot of laws exist in some places, but not in others, so references could be cited. For example legalizing cannabis  in the UK, could be compared to some states in america which have already done it.